# How can I substitute a list by index in python?

Tags: python, list

I need to write a function that contains 3 input parameters:

- A list called randome containing random integer numbers
- A list called indexes that contains (non-negative) indexes of items that need substitution by the third parameter. It is possible that indexes contains non-existent indexes for source. Check if the index actually exists in source before you substitute. Perhaps using the len of randome?
- A value new_value that we use to overwrite the items in source. Assign True as default value.

For example: `substitution_function([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 2], True)` must return this list: `[True, 2, True, 4, 5]`

Anyone have any ideas?

```
def substitution_function(randome, indexes, new_value=True):

    result = []
    for data in indexes:
        if data <= len(source):
            result.append(new_value)
        else:
            for i in range(len(source)):
                result.append(source[i])    
    return result
```

But this code can be greatly improved

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Comment: I have an idea, I even know how to do it in 30sec. But what have you tried ?

Comment: Yeah I've tried but my code is only half right

Comment: I'm not going to write any code. With that in mind, suppose you have this function: `substitution_function(target, indexes, val)`. 1) Iterate over `indexes` list. 2) Assign each position of `target` the value of `val`. If you need to return a copy, not the `target` itself, you may need to create a copy of target before starting the loop.

Comment: Sorry for any mistakes, I'm new here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you started is strange, let's start from scratch. There is 2 ways

1. Replace with the given value, at the given indexes

   ```py
   def substitution_function(source, indexes, new_value=True):
       for index in indexes:
           if index < len(source):
               source[index] = new_value
       return source
   ```
2. Build a whole new list, and conditionally use original value or replacement one

   ```py
   # that solution is safe-proof to invalid index
   def substitution_function(source, indexes, new_value=True):
       result = []
       indexes = set(indexes) # can be added in case of large list
       for i, data in enumerate(source):
           if i in indexes:
               result.append(new_value)
           else:
               result.append(data)
       return result
   ```

Comment: I really like the 2nd code, because that's exactly what I wanted to do! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Pythonppp you can think about accepting the answer so (green tick on left) ;)

Answer (score 0):

It runs for loop on `randome` with getting item's index by `enumerate()`. If index is in `indexes` it returns `new_value` to listcomp's list if it's not it returns item. The possible problem of spare indexes in `indexes` is solved by just not touching them at all.

```
def substitution_function(randome, indexes, new_value=True):
    return [new_value if e in indexes else i for e,i in enumerate(randome)]
```

Comment: "maybe" + poor naming + no explanation makes a very poor answer even if valid

Comment: @azro that's my bad, I've corrected my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to you read the [Stack Overflow Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

```py
def overwriteArr(arr, idxs, val):
    for idx in idxs:
        try:
            arr[idx] = val
        except:
            pass
    return arr

print(overwriteArr([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 2], True)) # [True, 2, True, 4, 5]
```

Comment: That "if" doesn't do the condition the OP asked for

Comment: The owner of this question said that he wanted to you first check if the index exists, so i made it, in a yet inefficient way. EDIT: trying it with a non existent index gives an error.

Comment: Thanks for the trust, I rarely points error that are not ^^

Comment: Thanks you too for alerting me of that :).